# Failed to allocate nodeid for API at <sql_node_ipaddr>. Returned error: 'No free node id found for mysqld(API).'

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

### OS and mysql cluster version

- **OS:** Linux centos7
- **mysql cluster:** mysql-cluster-community-7.5.8-1.el7.x86_64

### Server list

- 192.168.1.101  ndbd node1
- 192.168.1.102  ndbd node2
- 192.168.1.103  ndb_mgmd
- 192.168.1.104  mysql(api) node1
- 192.168.1.105  mysql(api) node2

The two data node(ndbd) is OK,but sql node(mysql) cannot connect to ndb_mgmd.The network is OK. SElinux and firewall is disabled.

### My config

mgmd config(/var/lib/mysql-cluster/config.ini)

```
[ndbd default]
NoOfReplicas=2
DataMemory=80M
IndexMemory=18M
ServerPort=2202

[ndb_mgmd]
HostName=192.168.1.103
DataDir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster

[ndbd]
HostName=192.168.1.101
NodeId=2
DataDir=/opt/mysql/data

[ndbd]
HostName=192.168.1.102
NodeId=3
DataDir=/opt/mysql/data

[mysqld]
HostName=192.168.1.104
```

mysql config(/etc/config.ini)

```
[mysqld]
user=mysql
ndbcluster
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

symbolic-links=0
default-storage-engine=NDBCLUSTER
ndb-connectstring=192.168.1.103

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

[mysql_cluster]
ndb-connectstring=192.168.1.103
```

### Error log

mgmd log

```
2017-11-27 20:28:35 [MgmtSrvr] WARNING  -- Failed to allocate nodeid for API at 192.168.1.104. Returned error: 'No free node id found for mysqld(API).'
2017-11-27 20:28:36 [MgmtSrvr] INFO     -- Alloc node id 4 failed, no new president yet
```

sql node log(mysqld)

```
2017-11-28T03:18:43.565265Z 4 [Warning] NDB: Failed to acquire global schema lock, error: (4009)Cluster Failure
2017-11-28T03:18:43.566664Z 4 [Warning] NDB: Failed to acquire global schema lock, error: (4009)Cluster Failure
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You started the management server fromt he wrong node, it is started
from 192.168.1.104, but in config it says it should be in
192.168.1.103.

2) You are missing a mysqld section for the second MySQL server at
192.168.1.105

Some recommendations:
1) Assign node ids to all nodes
2) Add an API node as well to enable running some NDB tools as well